# svn co does not get HEAD stops at an earlier revision

Tags: svn

I am trying to checkout my svn repository (ubuntu svn server and ubuntu client).

I do an svn co for a fresh checkout and it gets up to revision 11111 but the HEAD revision is 12145
On other systems (Windows) my svn browser sees all the revisions and sees 12145 as HEAD

Comment: Are both machines checking out EXACTLY the same path? Are both machines using the EXACTLY the same user credentials? How are you determining the rev of the checkout? ("svnversion ."?) What happens if you specify that you want 12145?

Comment: Yes , I quadruple checked the path to the repo and they are the same.  All I do is an svn co https://<repo>/path  I've even deleted the workspace, removed .svn and started fresh.  All other machines check out just fine.  Not sure why this machine arbitrarily stops at rev 11111

Comment: What svn client are you using under Windows? Try updating it, or try a different client? Also, what happens when you specify that you want '-r 12145'?

Comment: I use tortoise in windows, but the windows computers are getting all the revisions just fine.  The issue I am having is on an ubuntu box where I've checked out the code.  It sees 11111 as the head.  When I try to force a -r 12145 it says that revision does not exist.

Comment: If it were me, I'd try installing the command line version, and try a HEAD checkout. If it still gives the same message, fire off a `svn ls -r 126 https://<repo>/path ` and see if the list command returns different results than the checkout. Maybe that version of tortoise has a weird bug or something... running out of ideas. Maybe check the server log to see if it's doing some odd redirect or something?

Comment: The issue is happening on an ubuntu machine, not the windows machine.  Verified that the repo uses svn version 1.6.6 and so does the client ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL! Problem solved!

I had copied this computer from the computer that is hosting the svn repo.  Consequently when I tried to reach the repo, the copied repo was still running.

The head revision of the copied repo was created on 8-27-2012 and that in fact matched the date the server was creted in AWS.

So in the end, SVN is vindicated as doing what it is supposed to do.